# How do I view the blazemeter sense report when I run the jmx script via the terminal or Jenkins?

Tags: jmeter, jenkins, jmeter-plugins, test-report

Recently added the blazemeter sense uploader plugin for reporting purposes and it is really nice. Post running the script, you get a sense.jtl file and a url to view the reports on the browser with valid authentication. Please suggest how to view the blazemeter sense report when I run the jmx script via the terminal or Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux you can use [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command to fetch the URL from *jmeter.log* file like:

```
grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*/gui/[0-9]*/" jmeter.log | head -1
```

As a result it will produce URL to the results page like:

```
https://sense.blazemeter.com/gui/123456/
```

Which can be used for publishing as a build artifact in a form of HTML page, from [Jenkins pipeline](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial) perspective it would be something like:

```
sh "cat > sense.html <<'EOF'\n" +
                                "<html>" +
                                "<body>\n" +
                                "<a href="https://sense.blazemeter.com/gui/123456/">https://sense.blazemeter.com/gui/123456/</a>\n" +
                                "</body>\n" +
                                " </html>"
```

And then publish the generated HTML file to the Jenkins dashboard like:

```
step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'sense.html', fingerprint: true, latestOnly: true])
```

Comment: If I'm using windows then?